# how can I do so the progress bar count up(1,2,3,4...) when the window is not on top, and then start again count down to zero when it is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, progress-bar

I am trying to do, whenever someone clicks on a link I've got, it will open a new page. Once the page is opened, I want a progress bar and a timer to count down to zero (10,9,8,7.....,0).

The thing is, I only want the countdown and the progress bar to count down / run when the window is active. When the window / tab is not active or Window is not on top, I want the timer / progress bar to start the count up(1,2,3,4,5,6....), if back in this page again timer start to count down to zero.
At the moment the timer will just count down. Not stop when the window is not active or anything.

My problem is: how can I do so the progress bar count up(1,2,3,4...) when the window is not active or window is not on top, and then start again count down to zero when it is?

Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
function ptc_counter_start(){

        //var cnt =10;
        var cnt =[PTCSECOND];
        var counter123 = setInterval(function() {
            if (cnt>0) 
            {
                $('#displayCounter').html(" "+cnt+" ");
                cnt--;

                curcount=[PTCSECOND]-cnt;
                $('#progressbar div').width((curcount*100)/[PTCSECOND]+"%");
            }
            else 
            {
                clearInterval(counter123);
                document.getElementById("credittopframe").innerHTML="";
                $.ajax({
                                                                                                url: '[SITEURL]ptc/creditcounter',
                                                                                                type: 'POST',
                                                                                                data: {'id':[ID]},
                                                                                                success: function(data) {
                                                                                                    $('.link1, .link2').css({'display':'block'});
                        var member=document.getElementById("credittopframe");
                        if(member!==null) member.innerHTML=data;
                        window.opener.checkptc_ad([ID]);
                    }
                }); 


            }
        },1000);
    }
```

Comment: Do you think it does have to do with `conditional statement?` when the `Web_LostFocus` then increase the progressbar or when `Web_Focus` then decrease progressbar

Comment: I mean if the user leaves the webpage then increase the timer or if the user returns to the webpage decrease the timer

Comment: Can you write comment with example code? Thank you.

Comment: the best that i can give is an idea, im not too well learned with this P.L i hope it is VB.Net and if it is then you already have an answer yesterday hahaha

Comment: Good Luck on your coding

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyone who can give me answers?